# How to provide external path for step definition files in citrus cucmber

Tags: java, cucumber, citrus-framework

I have a code which is working fine until I change the path of glue code here is the working code

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="D:/citrus/Feature",
    strict = true,
    glue = { "todo" },      
    plugin = { "com.consol.citrus.cucumber.CitrusReporter" } )
public class TodoFeatureTest   {

}
```

I am able to specify external path i.e out side of eclipse project but when I want to specify external path for glue ={} option I am getting un implemented steps error what I can do for this. I want to specify step definition files outside of the project.

Answer (score 0):

cucumber.glue=    # comma separated package names. example: com.example.glue

see - https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#junit

the values for glue must be package names where to find the deep definitions, not paths

it really does not matter where you implement the step definitions (same project or external jars), as long as they are on test class path. make sure correct dependency is added for the test.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong you are saying it is impossible to specify stepdefinition files out side of project?? They must be with in project

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
features={"D:/citrus/Feature"}
```

Instead of:

```
features="D:/citrus/Feature"
```